# When to use the article tag

Tags: html, css

When exactly is it appropriate to use the article tag? I've looked it up, of course, and to my understanding it's most beneficial when coding for a series of information that can make sense by itself...but in that case, why not just use a div?

Comment: "The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content." A `div` is just a generic block element with no real semantic meaning. `article` is more specific and semantic for "article" content https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element

Answer (score 1):

> The `<article>` tag specifies independent, self-contained content.
>
> An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to
>   distribute it independently from the rest of the site.
>
> Potential sources for the `<article>` element:
>
> - Forum post
> - Blog post
> - News story
> - Comment

Source: [article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp)

Answer (score -3):

`<article>` tag is an independent tag. `<article>` is an HTML5 element whereas `<div>` is an HTML4 element.